# Play 2.0 scala tutorial - heroku failing due to evolution

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm following the Play 2.0 [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaTodoList) for Scala

Everything works fine until I try to push and run it on Heroku. after running "git push heroku master", the server crashes. Checking the logs, I see the following:

```
Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=37849 -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops`
2012-08-13T06:52:45+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 2
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:play
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: [warn] play - Your production database [default] needs evolutions! 
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: CREATE SEQUENCE task_id_seq;
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: label varchar(255)
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: CREATE TABLE task (
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('task_id_seq'),
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: );
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: # --- Rev:1,Ups - c5e3eee
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: [warn] play - Run with -DapplyEvolutions.default=true if you want to run them automatically (be careful)
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops, cannot start the server.
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]: PlayException: Database 'default' needs evolution! [An SQL script need to be run on your database.]
2012-08-13T06:52:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:422)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16):

Either if you use the embed DB or the PostgreSQL, Play doesn't have a support to apply evolution by hand...

But, as said in the error message, you can activate a configuration key in the application.conf file:
`applyEvolutions.default=true`

Enabling will tell Play to auto<sup>ly</sup> apply all evolutions!

But take with care to your update scripts... if you drop and recreate every incremental version => you'll kill all your data !

Comment: What is the correct way of using evolutions when updating our application?

Comment: My best guess is that ensure your incremental sal to be protective.. for instance no delete but update ti add or adapt the values.  With good IT tests, you'll be able to auto apply evolutions without any fear

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to andy's solution could be adding the following to the heroku [procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true
  -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=$DATABASE_URL
```

($PORT and $DATABASE_URL will be populated by environment variables on the Heroku side)

Answer (score -6):

You need a database. There are free addons in heroku

Comment: I did have the dependencies for PostgreSQL in my Build.scala file and specified in my Procfile. However, I did discover the issue - I had a typo in my Procfile and it was not loading properly. Definitely a rookie mistake!

Comment: the problem is caused by an evolution script that needs to execute. Setting the evolution script to execute automatically fixes this.